# Can the laravel _token be used to avoid submitting a form twice?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, forms

Correct me if I'm wrong, 
but basically the "_token" insert by laravel in each form as hidden field can't be used to avoid multiple submit of the same form?

Ive tried to compare it with the one stored in Session with the one sent in Post, but its always the same!
I've a page with some form, the controller make a redirect to another page if the store is ok, after if the user hits the backwards button the form is still the same (obviously served by cache browser's) and you can send it, again and again.

I've tried to empty all the field manually but this fail in case of "validation" not passed! Even to me set the "submit" button as "inactive" doesn't work for me. Any suggestion?

Comment: what do you mean by telling "again and again"? If you are getting redirected even to the same page, the form will be cleared right?

Comment: @KevinRED no, i redirect to another page, from the controller, then if the user hits the backwards button the cache serve the same page with the form with alla values, even the same file loaded.... againt&again--->multiple times

Comment: _token i don't think provides the thing that you wanted to restrict duplicate submission. I believe it is for the security reasons.

Comment: you right but i supposed that i can confront with the one stored in session, but was my mistake, so why do not implement a time stamp that doing the same?

Comment: Generate your own token in hidden form field, than store it with data or store it wherever you want and on each from submission check for token existence.
_token in Laravel is used for CSRF protection.

Comment: thousand o MB of framework and nobody cares about client's misunderstanding?

Comment: Well basically even though you are submitting the same copy according to laravel it is a form submission all so well...it is in my opinion the developer's duty to check whether it's duplicate or not